# How to create a speech bubble in which the arrow, or pointer, is part of the element, but the borders that make it are not?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
const profile = document.querySelector('#profile');
let timeDelay = "";

profile.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { 
    if(this.children.length != 0) { 
        clearTimeout(timeDelay);
        return;
    }
   const onHover = document.createElement('div');
   onHover.setAttribute('id', 'miniProfile');
   this.append(onHover)
   setTimeout(()=> {
       onHover.style.top = '120%';
       onHover.style.transition = '0.5s'
       onHover.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease'
   }, 10)
  
    const forArrowLeft = document.createElement('div');
    const forArrowRight = document.createElement('div');
    forArrowLeft.setAttribute('id', 'forArrowLeft')
    forArrowRight.setAttribute('id', 'forArrowRight')
    onHover.append(forArrowLeft)
    onHover.append(forArrowRight)

    forArrowRight.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        this.style.cursor = 'default'
        e.stopPropagation() 
        e.preventDefault()
    })
    forArrowLeft.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { 
        this.style.cursor = 'default'
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.preventDefault()
    })
    forArrowRight.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation() 
    })
    forArrowLeft.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) { 
        e.stopPropagation()
    })

    onHover.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { 
       clearTimeout(timeDelay)
       e.stopPropagation()
    })

})

profile.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) { 
    if(e.relatedTarget.id.toLowerCase() != this.children[0].id.toLowerCase()) {
        timeDelay = setTimeout(()=> {
            this.children[0].remove();   
        }, 500)      
    } 
})
```

```css
#profile { 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
    color: black;
}
 
#miniProfile { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url("https://media.architecturaldigest.com/photos/5da74823d599ec0008227ea8/16:9/w_2560%2Cc_limit/GettyImages-946087016.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#forArrowLeft { 
    position:absolute;
    height: 0;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: 15px solid white;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    left:0;
    width: 30px;
}

#forArrowRight {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 30px;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: 15px solid white;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<a id="profile" href="">My Profile</a>
```

What I wanna do is to make the arrow or pointer be part of the image itself in the sense that you can click on it, but the two elements, or borders that constructed the arrow to not be part of the element.

Previously I used pseudo-elements after and before to construct the pointer, but the rest of the two elements were still part of the image, even if you make them transparent, they're still there.

So, to solve that issue, I thought I have to stop the propagation of these pseudo-elements that create the pointer in order to separate it from the image, and for that reason, I had to opt for creating new elements and appending them instead of using the pseudo-elements. As you can see in the above example, the two appended elements that construct the pointer are in fact now separate from the image, or at least that's the effect, but now the issue is that, the pointer itself is also separate, and I want it to be part of the image. I want the pointer to be considered part of the image, child of the image element, but not the rest of the two elements `forArrowLeft` and `forArrowRIght` that constructed the pointed.

Is that even possible? If not, how can this be achieved? I saw this effect on Wikipedia, and I want to replicate it. You can just hover over any hyperlink in Wiki, and you'll see what I want to do.

Hopefully you understand what I mean. If you don't feel free to ask me for clarification.

Comment: Running the snippet just shows me a link - what is supposed to be shown? Also, it sounds messy to use separate elements. Would clip-path be useful?

Comment: When you hover over the link, you get a speech bubble with a pointer attached to it. I don't know how to use clip paths. All the suggestions for making a pointer is with after and before.

Comment: Can you use a clip path to make the same kind of arrow pointer like in the snippet?

Comment: Try a polygon. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of how would you do the arrow pointer attached to an element like in my snippet using clip path? I've never used that before. Can you use jsfiddle to give me a simple demonstration? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clip-path using a polygon would keep the arrow part within the clickable area.

Here's a very simple example. Obviously the values can be changed to make the exact shape required:

```css
.bubble {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 5%, 10% 5%, 15% 0, 20% 5%, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 0 100% );
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

Comment: I can't believe how much more easy and simple it is to create arrow pointer with this `clip-path`. Why does everyone keep using the `after` and `before` pseudo-elements to make an arrow? I guess in a way it's easier to do it with the old trick of using the borders of pseudo-elements. `Clip-path` while very useful, and clean, it's difficult to learn how to do polygon. Thanks again for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: To add to @IloveCoffee's comment, I'm also glad I found this solution of using `clip-path`! No one else is suggesting that, and it's such a great solution. However, I too struggled for a moment to understand how `polygon` worked, but thanks to Mozilla's documentation, I was able to piece it together. In case it's helpful for anyone else with the same struggle, I was able to achieve a standard basic speech bubble cutout with the speech tick in the center of the bottom edge, by using: `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 60% 85%, 50% 100%, 40% 85%, 0% 85%)`